# I need to stop displaying the last symbol in a System.out..print(); in Java

Tags: java

I'm practically adding a comma, after each element from an array. At the end of the `.print();` I would like to, either replace the comma with a dot or not display the comma at all anymore. But I'm not looking for fancy String methods to do that! I want to do it as simple as possible, within the `System.out.print();` if possible at all... creating new whole methods, just to have this done is too much of a strain on my app(out of scope)! Are there ways to achieve this goal?

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Person Luigi = new Person("Luigi", "Mascarpone", 1985, "brown", "Farmer", true);
        Person Giancarlo = new Person("Giancarlo", "Bebeto", 1980, "green", "Banker", true);
        Person Marietta = new Person("Marietta", "Cardinale", 1990, "blue", "Acountant", false);
        Person Claudia = new Person("Claudia", "Pepino", 1995, "brown", "Nurse", false);

        Person persons[] = {Luigi, Giancarlo, Marietta, Claudia};
        Person personal[] = new Person[4];
        personal[0] = Luigi;
        personal[1] = Giancarlo;
        personal[2] = Marietta;
        personal[3] = Claudia;

        filterPers(personal);
    }

public static void filterPers(Person personal[]) {

        System.out.print("The persons contained within the array, are: ");
        for(Person n : personal) {
            System.out.print(n.name + ", ");
        }
}
```

The output looks like this:

The persons contained within the array, are: `Luigi, Giancarlo, Marietta, Claudia,`

So I basically, either wish to replace the last comma with a dot or remove it entirely.

Comment: OK. Have you thought about a way to do that? It's not that hard. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: When you iterate over something, there is usually a way to (a) figure out how many elements you're going to iterate over and (b) keep track of what item you're currently iterating over. Together, this will allow you to amend the logic in your loop to do things differently for the last item you're iterating over. I think this should be enough information for you to figure it out? :)

Comment: Why the down-votes?? =( I don't get it... what I've described here, is difficult enough for a beginner like me to conceive! And from the answers I've seen so far, it can get quite difficult!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but here's my guess: code could be closer to a [mcve], and it doesn't look like you attempted to solve it yourself. (We get way too many "do my work for me" questions here.)

Comment: @Dragos I know that downvotes are discouraging, but here is the thing: SO tries to be a resource of high quality, broadly applicable questions and answers; in other words, every question should strive to be useful for others in the future. In order to achieve this, we hold questions to a very high standard (so high, in fact, that it can sometimes be difficult even for long-term members and advanced coders to meet it). This seems harsh, but it is exactly what makes SO the main resource for programmer's today. Just try to improve over time and you'll be fine. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think thats the most simple solution to this problem:

```
public static void filterPers(Person personal[]) {

    System.out.print("The persons contained within the array, are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < personal.length-1;i++) {
        Person currentPerson = personal[i];
        if (i==personal.length-1)
            System.out.print(currentPerson.name);
        else
            System.out.print(currentPerson.name + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sure that you have you tested this? This doesn't work because of an error in the method.

Comment: what exactly are you getting, when performing the code?

Comment: it should be ```if (i==personal.length - 1)``` btw

Comment: As alvinalvord already said, `i` can never reach the value of `personal.length`. If you post something, make sure you test your code.

Comment: thank you for telling me! Was not able to test, because I was to lazy to create the Person class. Edited the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using for-each loop for joining, you could use `String.join(",", <string array>)`. This method will take care of joining elements with `,` and not having `,` at the end

Comment: Note that `String.join` was added in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Does your version of java allow to use a StringJoiner? If so, please try:

```
public static void filterPers(Person personal[]) {

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
    System.out.print("The persons contained within the array, are: ");
    for(Person n : personal) {
        sj.add(n.name);
    }
    System.out.println(sj.toString());

}
```

Comment: Good one sir! The simplest way to do it so far... =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update java with minium 8 so that you can be aware of Stream api in java.
Using stream you can achieve this

```
 public static void filterPers(Person personal[]) {

        System.out.println("The persons contained within the array, are: ");
        String nameCollect = Stream.of(personal)
                .map(person -> person.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(nameCollect);
}
```

Comment: I am on JDK 8! This method does work, but it's way too fancy for my beginner level! =P    Thumbs up though! =)